# Заполнить два массива случайными числами без повторений

Tags: php

Заполнить два массива случайными числами, так чтобы числа в этих двух массивов не повторялись.Заполнение должно происходить с помощью rand.

```
define ("B" , 4);
define ("C" , 4);
$D = [];
$E = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < B; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < C; $j++){
        $D[$i] = rand(0 , 8);
        $E[$j] = rand(0 , 8);
    }
}
foreach ($D as $V){
    foreach ($E as $B){
        if (array($V) == array($B)){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Слишком обобщенно! Прикрепите свой пример, что не получается?

Comment: Так вам нужно только заполнить уникальными значениями? Или заполнить с помощью `rand()` и проверить, что не повторяется?

Comment: Заполнить с помощью rand() так чтобы в первом и во втором массиве не было повторяющихся чисел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr1 = [];
$arr2 = [];
$temp = range(1, 10);
shuffle($temp);

foreach ($temp as $i => $int) {
    $i & 1 ? $arr1[] = $int : $arr2[] = $int;
}

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
```

---

**UPD**:

> *Заполнение должно происходить с помощью rand*

```
$temp = [];

do {
    $rand = rand(0, 10);
    $temp[$rand] = $rand;
} while (count($temp) < 10);

list($arr1, $arr2) = array_chunk($temp, sizeof($temp) / 2);

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
```

Comment: Заполнение должно происходить с помощью rand

Answer (score 0):

Перемешиваем случайно массив уникальных чисел, а потом рубим его на две части.

```
$a = range(1, 10);
usort($a, function($a, $b){return rand(-1, 1);});
[$foo, $bar] = array_chunk($a, 5);
echo implode(", ", $foo) . "\n"; // 5, 1, 2, 6, 7
echo implode(", ", $bar) . "\n"; // 3, 4, 8, 9, 10
```

Осторожно! Такой хак с сортировкой через rand даёт не очень приятную глазу "случайность".